# PHP class property reference to an object

Tags: php, oop

```
class Hello {
    public function hi() {
        echo "Hello, hi!\n";
    }
}

class ParentClass {
    public $obj;
    public function __construct() {
       $this->obj = new Hello;
    }
}

class Test extends ParentClass {
     public function __construct() { 
        $this->obj->hi();
     }
}

$temp = new Test;
```

The error message I get is "Call to a member function hi() on a non-object". $obj should  be referencing to an instance of the class "Hello", but it obviously is not - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$obj != $this->obj `

Comment: I just forgot the $this when copying the code.

Comment: I am not sure but probably the parent class constructor was not called automatically

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `__construct()` in your `Test` class but not calling the parent constructor.  If you want the parent constructor to execute, you need to explicitly specify so.  Add a call to `ParentClass` constructor in in `Test` class constructor.

```
class Test extends ParentClass {
     public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->obj->hi();
     }
}
```

Also as @Tasos Bitsios pointed in his comment you also need to update your `ParentClass` constructor as follows:

```
class ParentClass {
    public $obj;
    public function __construct() {
       $this->obj = new Hello; // Use $this->obj and not just $obj.
    }
}
```

Comment: and also: in ParentClass constructor: $this->obj= rather than $obj=

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is there are rule for when I have to call the constructor explicitly?

Comment: @TasosBitsios, Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php "Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private)." EDIT: link

Answer (score 0):

You need call to parent constructor:

```
class Test extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->obj->hi();
    }
}
```